# Why does plugging headphone jack in stop internal speakers to working (even after headphones are unplugged)?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, sound-card, dell-latitude

I recently bought a **Dell latitude E6420 i5-2520M 8GB** and I am experiencing a very annoying issue with the speakers.

The sound coming from the laptop's internal speakers works until I plug the headphone jack into the computer for the first time.  **When I unplug the headphones, the internal speakers do not come back on.**

**What I have tried so far with no success:**

- Uninstall and reinstall audio/sound drivers
- Tried Realtek drivers
- Disabled headphones
- Recovery and reinstall Windows 10

Every time I uninstall and reinstall the sound drivers the speakers start to work again until I plug in and then remove the headphones.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I have several DELL machines and that's the expected behavior.  Do the speakers work again if you unplug the headphones?

Comment: No, they don't. Speakers stop to work completely even when I unplug the headphone. The only thing that help is uninstall and reinstall again the driver.

Comment: Maybe the question was not clear - problem here is that the jack somehow affect the internal speakers completely (even after I unplug the headphone...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Realtek drivers on the Dell Latitude (see [here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19541469)) - You'll have to [install the Windows Native Audio Driver](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/p/19589727/20650645.aspx#20650645).

Comment: I thought the native drivers installed in my laptop were the Windows Native Audio Driver - but it was not the case... That resolved my issue.